# Import doc (word) file to stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

How can i Import doc file to stimulsoft report?

When click file tab
And click open button
I can upload file but only mrt file
are acceptable

RTF file shows white screen

I want upload doc or docx file

Has anyone done this before?
Or is it possible??